# When a manifold is isometric to a product manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, foliations

Let  $M$  be a Riemannian smooth manifold of dimension p and  $\phi$ a smooth submersion from $M$ to some other smooth manifold $N$ of dimension q. Denote by $\mathcal{F}$ the foliation of leaves $\phi^{-1}(z)$ for $z\in \phi(M)$. When can we say that $M$ is isomorphic to a product manifold of the form $L\times S$ where $L$ is a leave of $\mathcal{F}$ passing through a point $x_0$ and $S$ is a transversal leave passing through the same point $x_0$.

A classical condition in ([1], Theorem 4.4 section 4.4) says that if $M$ is complete simply connected and if $\mathcal{F}$ is parallel then $M$ is isomorphic to such product manifold. But I don't know what condition $\phi$ should satisfy to ensure that $\mathcal{F}$ is parallel?

Are there more general conditions on $\phi$ to ensure that $M$ can be seen as a product manifold?

[1] A. Bejancu and H. R. Farran. Foliations and Geometric Structures. Springer Science & Business Media, Jan. 2006. Google-Books-ID: NtqEFj4nYecC.

Comment: Something's wrong with your setup. If $\phi$ is an embedding, then the "leaves" $\phi^{-1}(z)$ are just single points, so the foliation is trivial.

Comment: thank you Jack Lee for pointing this out, it was a mistake, $\phi$ needs to be a submersion.